# Using Factory Girl step definitions in Cucumber features (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, factory-bot

I'm trying to use Cucumber and Factory Girl. The following lines:

```
  Given I am not logged in
  And   the following user exists:
    | login  | email               | password   | confirmation |
    | user50 | user50@mydomain.com | secret50   | secret 50    | 
 ....
```

raises the following error:

```
Undefined step: "the following user exists:" (Cucumber::Undefined exception)
/home/user/RubymineProjects/project/features/sign_in.feature:9:in `And the following user exists:

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:
And /^the following user exists:$/ do |table|
  # table is a Cucumber::Ast::Table
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

'

I've installed factory_girl_rails (even RubyMine's code completion feature works with Factory Girl step ... )

```
#Gemfile
group :test do
   gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 0.3.2"
   gem "factory_girl_rails"
 end

#features/support/env.rb
require 'factory_girl'
require 'factory_girl/step_definitions'
```

Any ideas? Thanks

---

Update: Thanks to @sj26 and @twmills  I realized that I forgot to create a :user factory with Factory Girl. Once I created it, everything worked well.

Comment: Do you have a users.rb factory file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For those people, who trying to use FactoryGirl helpers now:

From FactoryGirl 3.5.0 these step helpers are deprecated and removed in 4.0.0: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/25650434584/writing-better-cucumber-scenarios-or-why-were

> As of FactoryGirl 3.5.0, using any of FactoryGirl’s generated step
>   definitions will print out a deprecation warning. We’ll be removing
>   the step definitions completely in the 4.0.0 release of FactoryGirl in
>   accordance with SemVer. I imagine the existing code will be extracted
>   to a gem similar to Cucumber Rails’ training wheels with a nice
>   warning urging developers not to use the the steps.

So if you want to use FactoryGirl in Cucumber you should use it in your own step definitions.

Comment: ok. if your answers gets at least 3 upvotes I will consider marking your answer as the right answer. (I do not use cucumber anymore so i cannot check)

Answer (score 7):

You need to include your factories first. [`factory_girl/step_definitions`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/4f5f5d/lib/factory_girl/step_definitions.rb#L31) will iterate over your defined factories to define a step for each.

I use this in `features/support/factory_girl.rb`:

```
# Require factories...
require 'spec/factories'

# Then define steps based on factories.
require 'factory_girl/step_definitions'
```

Comment: I'm getting `no such file to load -- spec/factories (LoadError)` even though I have that folder and some factories I (successfully) use in rspec tests. I have also tried with `require '../../spec/factories'` but still no luck. As usual, RubyMine's code completion finds everything ... Very annoying, I would like to use the default steps provided by Factory Girl and not write my own..

Comment: Are you sure you have a `factory :user`?

Can you [gist](https://gist.github.com) your user model, factories file, cucumber support and cucumber feature?

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem. I didn't have the :user factory. Sorry, it was a newbie question (I'm using Factory Girl for the first time)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb

```
Given /^the following user exists:$/ do |users|
  users.hashes.each do |user|
    Factory(:user,user)
  end
end
```

Although you may want this instead:

```
Given /^the following users:$/ do |users|
  etc..
```

Comment: This duplicates the functionality of factory_girl's step_definitions, but WETly.

Comment: Exactly, I would like to uses the factory_girl's step_definitions if possible. (If I can't, I will probably use this workaround). Thanks @sj26 and @MacksMind

Comment: @sj26 Old habits are hard to break. Factory Girl didn't include step definitions when I started using it. Need to make the switch.

Comment: So how would you write the step definitions using the factory_girl's step_definitions ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I get that ThoughtBot wants us to write better code, but as an upgrade crutch, we can just put this old file in features/step_definitions:

https://raw.github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/3.6.x/lib/factory_girl/step_definitions.rb